# React Native View does not want to grow

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

View components don't want to grow based on their flex properties.
The container should get the entire height, while every view inside should take half, one the upper and one the lower half of the screen.

Component:

```
<View>
            <StatusBar />
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.upperAreaContainer}>
                    <Text>iufewkjgb</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.controlsContainer}>
                    <Text>giriku</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
```

Styling:

```
{
  "container": {
    "flexBasis": 1,
    "flexDirection": "column",
    "flexGrow": 1,
    "flexShrink": 1,
  },
  "controlsContainer": {
    "alignItems": "center",
    "backgroundColor": "#7a2e2e",
    "flexBasis": 0.5,
    "flexGrow": 1,
    "flexShrink": 1,
  },
  "upperAreaContainer": {
    "backgroundColor": "royalblue",
    "flexBasis": 0.5,
  },
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'; 
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  return (
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <StatusBar/>
            <View style={{flex:1 , backgroundColor:'red'}}>
                <View style={{flex:0.5, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                    <Text>iufewkjgb</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{flex:0.5, backgroundColor:'pink'}}>
                    <Text>giriku</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
  );
}
```

I think this is what you want to get, both children takes the half of the screen.

Comment: sorry, it does not work